# Convert Dataframe column of list with dictionaries into seperate columns and expand Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas Dataframe and managed to get some things done, but I'm totally stuck with this problem:

I have a dataframe table that looks like this:

|  | id | price | shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7 | [{code:{location: 'beach', guests: '300'}, text:{textvalue:'beautiful'}},{code:{location: 'forest', guests: '200'}, text:{textvalue:'far away'}}] |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | [{code:{location: 'beach', guests: '500'}, text:{textvalue:'overcrowded'}},{code:{location: 'forest', guests: '200'}, text:{textvalue:'far away'}}] |
| 2 | 2 | 9 | [{code:{location: 'mountain', guests: '300'}, text:{textvalue:'cold at night'}}] |
| 3 | 2 | 7 | [] |

I want to explode the list in column 'shop'. If the List is not empty, then i want to get the 'location' and 'textvalue'. since sometime there is more than one dict in the list , i want to make the table longer with one location/textvalue per id.

so it looks like:

|  | id | price | shop.location | shop.textvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7 | beach | beautiful |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | forest | far away |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | beach | overcrowded |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | forest | far away |
| 4 | 2 | 9 | mountain | too cold |
| 5 | 2 | 7 | NA | NA |

I tried a lot of different approaches, using .explode(). apply() and iterating. But i did not have found a way through yet.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quiet clear how your input data looks like and if it is valid, but you could also read your nested `JSON` or list of dicts to `dataframe` using `pandas.normalize()`.

```
pd.json_normalize(data, 'shop', ['id','price'])
```

###### Example

```
data = [
    {
    'id':1,
    'price':7,
    'shop':[{'code':{'location': 'beach', 'guests': '300'}, 'text':{'textvalue':'beautiful'}},{'code':{'location': 'forest', 'guests': '200'}, 'text':{'textvalue':'far away'}}]
    },
    {
    'id':1,
    'price':8,
    'shop':[{'code':{'location': 'beach', 'guests': '500'}, 'text':{'textvalue':'overcrowded'}},{'code':{'location': 'forest', 'guests': '200'}, 'text':{'textvalue':'far away'}}]
    }
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'shop', ['id','price'])
df = df[df.columns.tolist()[-2:] + df.columns.tolist()[:-2]]
df.columns = [c.replace('code','shop') for c in df.columns]
df
```

###### Output

|  | id | price | shop.location | shop.guests | text.textvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7 | beach | 300 | beautiful |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | forest | 200 | far away |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | beach | 500 | overcrowded |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | forest | 200 | far away |